# How to randomly assign button content and colour?

Tags: c#, wpf

I can't think of a way to currently assign the content and matching colour of a button randomly and I would be very thankful if someone could help me.

Currently the code to assign my button content and colour is

```
    public void SetButtonContent(TextBlock reagentText, TextBlock transMetalText,
    Button opt1, Button opt2, Button opt3, Button opt4, Button opt5, Button opt6, Button opt7, Button opt8)
    {
        string pickedMetal = CycleThroughMetals(); //randomly picks a metal 
        string pickedReagent = CycleThroughReagents(); //randomly picks reagent

        reagentText.Text = pickedReagent;
        transMetalText.Text = pickedMetal;

        BrushConverter bc = new BrushConverter();  
        switch (pickedMetal)
        {
            case "Copper":
                opt1.Content = string.Format("{0} \n {1} \n{2}",Cu.hexAqColour, Cu.hexAqFormula, Cu.hexAqState);
                opt1.Background = Brushes.Blue;

                opt2.Content = string.Format("{0} \n {1} \n{2}",Cu.dilNaOHRctColour, Cu.dilNaOHRctFormula, Cu.dilNaOHRctState);
                opt2.Background = Brushes.Blue;

                opt3.Content = string.Format("{0} \n {1}",Cu.excessNaOHColour, Cu.excessNaOHFormula, Cu.excessNahOHState);
                opt3.Background = Brushes.Blue;

                opt4.Content = string.Format("{0} \n {1} \n{2}", Cu.dilNH3RctColour, Cu.dilNH3RctFormula, Cu.dilNH3RctState);
                opt4.Background = Brushes.Blue;

                opt5.Content = string.Format("{0} \n {1} \n{2}",Cu.ExcessNH3Colour, Cu.ExcessNH3Formula, Cu.ExcessNH3State);
                opt5.Background = Brushes.DarkBlue;

                opt6.Content = string.Format("{0} \n {1} \n{2}",Cu.saltRctColour, Cu.saltRctFormula, Cu.saltRctState);

                opt7.Content = string.Format("{0} \n {1} \n{2}",Cu.Na2CO3RctColour, Cu.Na2CO3RctFormula, Cu.Na2CO3RctState);
                opt7.Background = Brushes.Blue;

                opt8.Content = string.Format("{0} \n {1} \n{2}",Cu.ClRctColour, Cu.ClRctFormula, Cu.ClRctState);
                opt8.Background = Brushes.Yellow;
                break;


            default:
                break;
        }
```

I've only included one case with in my switch statement just to make it easier to read but in my code there is 6 cases but all perform pretty much the same function.

But I'd like to assign the button content randomly rather than manually but I'm unsure how to do this.

I'd also greatly appreciate any constructive criticism as I am quite a beginner in regards to WPF and C#.

Comment: Just to clarify: You have 8 buttons and 8 pieces of content, and you would like to randomly assign the 8 pieces of content to the 8 buttons?

Comment: @goobering yes that's correct :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple solution would be storing your buttons, contents and colors inside lists, randomizing them and then assigning their values like this:

```
public void SetButtonContent(TextBlock reagentText, TextBlock transMetalText,
    Button opt1, Button opt2, Button opt3, Button opt4, Button opt5, Button opt6, Button opt7, Button opt8)
{
    string pickedMetal = CycleThroughMetals(); //randomly picks a metal 
    string pickedReagent = CycleThroughReagents(); //randomly picks reagent

    List<Button> buttons = new List<Button>{opt1, opt2, opt3, opt4, opt5, opt6, opt7, opt8};
    List<Tuple<string, Brush>> contentsAndColors;

    reagentText.Text = pickedReagent;
    transMetalText.Text = pickedMetal;

    BrushConverter bc = new BrushConverter();  
    switch (pickedMetal)
    {
        case "Copper":
            contentsAndColors = new List<Tuple<string, Brush>>{
                new Tuple<string, Brush>(string.Format("{0} \n {1} \n{2}",Cu.hexAqColour, Cu.hexAqFormula, Cu.hexAqState), Brushes.Blue),
                new Tuple<string, Brush>(string.Format("{0} \n {1} \n{2}",Cu.dilNaOHRctColour, Cu.dilNaOHRctFormula, Cu.dilNaOHRctState), Brushes.Blue ),
                new Tuple<string, Brush>(string.Format("{0} \n {1}",Cu.excessNaOHColour, Cu.excessNaOHFormula, Cu.excessNahOHState),Brushes.Blue ),
                new Tuple<string, Brush>(string.Format("{0} \n {1} \n{2}", Cu.dilNH3RctColour, Cu.dilNH3RctFormula, Cu.dilNH3RctState),Brushes.Blue ),
                new Tuple<string, Brush>(string.Format("{0} \n {1} \n{2}",Cu.ExcessNH3Colour, Cu.ExcessNH3Formula, Cu.ExcessNH3State),Brushes.DarkBlue ),
                new Tuple<string, Brush>(string.Format("{0} \n {1} \n{2}",Cu.saltRctColour, Cu.saltRctFormula, Cu.saltRctState),Brushes.Blue ),
                new Tuple<string, Brush>(string.Format("{0} \n {1} \n{2}",Cu.Na2CO3RctColour, Cu.Na2CO3RctFormula, Cu.Na2CO3RctState),Brushes.Yellow ),
                new Tuple<string, Brush>(string.Format("{0} \n {1} \n{2}",Cu.ClRctColour, Cu.ClRctFormula, Cu.ClRctState),Brushes.Blue );
            };
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    //ensure buttons, contents and colors are of the same size
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(buttons.Count != contents.Count || buttons.Count != colors.Count, "Lists are not same in size");

    //randomize the order
    Random rng = new Random();
    buttons.OrderBy(x => rng.Next());
    contentsAndColors.OrderBy(x => rng.Next());
    //assign content and color to buttons
    for(int iButton = 0; iButton < buttons.Count; ++iButton)
    {
        buttons[iButton].Content = contentsAndColors[iButton].Item1;
        buttons[iButton].Background = contentsAndColors[iButton].Item2;
    }
}
```

As for the general tips/criticism:

The `OrderBy(x => rng.Next());` statement combines linq and lambda mechanics which are very useful in manipulating lists, and lambda mechanics are generally useful in a multitude of ways, i'd suggest reading up on them.

About `OrderBy(x => rng.Next());`: Did you creating an Enum for your metals instead of using strings? this way you will be safe against typos and such, as the compiler will check those for you. you can simply create an enum this way:

```
public enum Metals
{ 
    Copper,
    Iron,
    Gold
}
```

And later you can use its values this way:

```
switch (pickedMetal)
{ 
    case Metals.Copper:
```

You could also consider using a parameter list in your method declaration if the numbers of buttons will change over developement time:

```
public void SetButtonContent(TextBlock reagentText, TextBlock transMetalText, params Button[] opts)
{
    Button opt1 = opts[0];
}
```

`params` is a keyword which allows you to write multiple objects in the call of a function which will then be combined into an array. As such your previous calls of `SetButtonContent` won't be harmed.

Comment: Thank you so much! the issue I'm having with this is that each button has to be a specific colour rather than a random one, so for instance if a button contains the hexaaqua string then it needs to be blue and so on

Comment: I'm getting the error code 'An exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.', what does this mean?

Comment: you should check the line this exception occured, usually this means that you try to access an enumaration's (like a list) element that isn't there. like calling colors[9] if your color has only 5 elements. Also be aware that indexing starts at 0, so if you have an enumeration with 1 element you can access it via listVariable[0].

Comment: I edited the answer so the color is now dependant on the content as they are bound to the same element in the list which is randomized. Please ensure to edit your question to reflect this different requested behaviour